# Passing static class reference into generic parameter causes error

Tags: typescript, generics

Well, before I open a ticket at github I wanna make sure that I'm not doing anything wrong. I hope that the problem is self explanatory:

```
class A {}

class B {
  static A = A;
}

function a<T>(a: T) {}

// this is fine
const b = new B.A;

// "B" refers only to a type but is used as a namespace.
a<B.A>(1);
```

Shouldn't I be able to refer to a type this way?

Also, while the instantiation infers the types as:

```
b = A
B.A = typeof A
B = B
```

It infers this for the last line:

```
B = any
```

Therefore, VS Code can jump to the definition for the first, but isn't able to find references for the second.

To be, this seems pretty odd.

UPDATE:
The first answer I received proved wrong, since this syntax will lead to a typeof of a typeof:

```
// arguments of type "A" cannot be assigned to parameters of type "typeof A", property "prototype" is missing.
a<(typeof B)['A']>(b);
```

Even if I add an explicit constructor type things are just getting worse:

```
// this will make things worse
class B {
  static A: { new (): A } = A;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't I be able to refer to a type this way?

No, not in TypeScript.

When you have

```
class A {}

class B {
  static A = A;
}
```

You you can use `B.A` as a value only, not a type. This can be confusing, because classes in TypeScript can be used both as values and as types, but only classes behave like that, anything else is different.

So `B.A` is a value, it's value is `class A`, and the type of this value is `typeof A` (`typeof A` is what you get when you use class in a type position, not value position).

If you need to use the **type** of `B.A` as a generic type argument, you can do this:

```
a<(typeof B)['A']>(A);
```

explanation: `A` is a member of `static part` of B class. You refer to static part of a class with `typeof B`, and you refer to a member type with `[]` which is [indexed access type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types).

This function `a` above accepts a constructor of class `A`. If you actually want function `a` to accept an instance of `A`, you should declare `B.A` differently:

```
class A {}

class B {
  static A: A;
}
```

now this compiles

```
a<(typeof B)['A']>(new A());
```

**UPDATE**

If you want `B.A` to be initialized to `A`'s constructor, but still be able to access instance side of `A`, you have to wait until TypeScript 2.8. It [will have a feature that enables obtaining instance type from constructor type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496) - this code compiles after `npm i typescript@next`:

```
class A {}

class B {
  static A = A;
}

function a<T>(a: T) { }

const b = new B.A;

type Constructor<T> = { new(...args: any[]): T };

type Instance<C> = C extends Constructor < infer T > ? T : never;

a<Instance<(typeof B)['A']>>(b);
```

Comment: While this make sense in a way, it doesn't make in another. I could use A as generic parameter directly while, as you said, its a value (but also a type). Same should, if you ask me, go for B in this case, since its also acting as value and type because: `B.A === typeof A` and `type C = typeof B['A'] === typeof A`. Sure, there will be reasons for this, but I think I still gonna open an issue because I think this should be naturally supported. It doesn't feel right when classes suddenly getting value only treated in such cases.

Comment: And just to clarify: You don't need parentheses for the typeof resolution, since typeof already introduces the right treatment for B. This does not really make it better, but a little bit less messy. I'll update that for you and accept your answer. Update: No I can't update it. Not enough characters to change :)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I have to revoke. This solution does not work because it leads to a typeof of a typeof. Parentheses or not.

Comment: If A and B are classes, you can use A and B as types (everywhere, in declarations and as  generic parameters), but you can't use `A.B` as a type - there is no dot notation for types in TypeScript, not likely to happen. Also, I put paretheses around `(typeof B)` because for me `typeof B['A']` reads as `typeof (B['A'])` (which by the way is not allowed until type-position `typeof` is [fixed to accept arbitrary expressions](https://github.com/microsoft/typescript/issues/6606).

Comment: @Jean with `B.A` initialized as `static A = A`, I don't think there is a solution until TypeScript 2.8 - I updated the answer.